# Posting username and password using python bottle

Tags: python, bottle

I am learning bottle and I came across the login example on their website. It looks something like this:

```
@route('/login')
def login():
    return '''
        <form action="/login" method="post">
            username: <input name="username" type="text" />
            password: <input name="password" type="password" />
            <input value="Login" type="submit" />
        </form>
            '''

@route('/login', method='POST') 
def do_login():
    username = request.forms.post('username')
    password = request.forms.post('password')
    if check_login(username, password):
        return "<p>You have logged in successfuly</p>"
    else:
        return "<p>Your log in attempt has failed</p>"
```

What I expected from looking at the code was being able to input a username and password and see either the success message or the failure message. However I kept receiving `Internal server error` message.

I tried doing something like this as well:

`if username=='username' and password=='password'`

I know it is not pretty but at this point I am not sure how it all works. This gives the same error.

Comment: Did you implement `check_login`? Is there anything logged in the console?

Comment: @minitech its part of the bottle library as far as I know. Got it to work though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left it and tried it back at work instead of at home and got it working with the previous version. To clarify the code now is as follows:

```
@route('/login')
def login():
    return '''
        <form action="/login" method="post">
            username: <input name="username" type="text" />
            password: <input name="password" type="password" />
            <input value="Login" type="submit" />
        </form>
           '''

@route('/login', method='POST') 
def do_login():
    username = request.forms.get('username')
    password = request.forms.get('password')
    if username==username and password==password
        return "<p>You have logged in successfuly</p>"
    else:
        return "<p>Your log in attempt has failed</p>"
```

So changing `request.forms.post` to `request.forms.get`

Afterwards I did my own version of `check_login`:

```
 usernames = ["username", "user"]
 passwords = ["password", "pass"]
 def check_login(username, password):
     if username in usernames and password in passwords:
         return True
     else:
         return False
```

and changed validation to:

```
    if check_login(username, password) is True:
        return "<p>You have logged in succesfully</p>"
    else:
        return "<p>Logging in attempt failed</p>"
```